# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\{x \in X : |f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$ converges for each $\epsilon > 0$, then $f_n \to 0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$.  Suppose that the infinite series
>   $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\{x \in X : |f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$ converges for each $\epsilon > 0.$  Prove that $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ a.e.

I am not really sure how to approach this problem.  Some help would be awesome.  Thanks.  It is a past qual problem.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I let $E_n^\epsilon = \{x \in X : |f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$  I noticed that the intersection of all $E_n^\epsilon$ for fixed epsilon must be zero if the statement is true for all epsilon.  Is proving this helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\{x \in X : |f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon\} =  \mu(\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty1_{ |f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon}) < \infty$$ which means $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty1_{ |f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon}$ is finite $\mu$-a.e.

That is to say for any $\epsilon$, there are only finitely many $n$ such that $|f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon$

Comment: Can you please explain, in the first line how did you interchange the measure and the summation ? what is the meaning of measure of the summation?

Comment: @GA316 Since $1_{ |f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon}$ is non-negative, we can use monotone convergence theorem. $\mu(f)$ means the integration of $f$ w.r.t $\mu$

Comment: Sorry. I am confused. What is the meaning of measure of a function. In your last command, you have mentioned the characteristic function and you have find the measure of those characteristic function in your answer. please tell what is the meaning of it.

Comment: @GA316 $\mu(A)$ for a set $A$ means the measure of $A$. $\mu(f)$ for a function $f$ means the integration of $f$. With these two definitions we have $\mu(A) = \mu(1_A)$

Comment: I am sorry. This is the first time I come across this notation $\mu (f)$. Thanks.

Comment: @GA316 You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Denote $E =\{x : f_n(x) \to 0\}$. We prove that
$$E = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m =1}^\infty \bigcap_{l=m}^\infty \left\{x: |f_l(x)| \leq \frac 1k\right\}.$$
Denote the set in right hand side by $F$. If $x\in E$ then $f_n(x) \to 0$, hence for any $k\geq 1$, there exists $m$ dependings on $k$ such that $|f_l(x)| \leq 1/k$ for any $l\geq m$. This shows that $x\in F$. Conversely, if $x\in F$, for any $\epsilon >0$, choosing $k_0$ such that $1/k_0 < \epsilon$ since $x\in F$ then 
$$x\in \bigcup_{m =1}^\infty \bigcap_{l=m}^\infty \left\{x: |f_l(x)| \leq \frac 1{k_0}\right\}.$$
This means that there exists $m$ such that $|f_l(x) |\leq 1/k_0 < \epsilon$ for any $l\geq m$. This means that $f_n(x) \to 0$, or $x\in E$. Hence $E =F$.

We have
$$E^c = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{l=m}^\infty \left\{x : |f_l(x)| >\frac1k\right\}. $$
Hence
$$\mu(E^c) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu\left(\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{l=m}^\infty \left\{x : |f_l(x)| >\frac1k\right\}\right)\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{m\to\infty} \mu\left(\cup_{l=m}^\infty \left\{x : |f_l(x)| >\frac1k\right\}\right).$$
From our assumptions, we have
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \mu\left(\cup_{l=m}^\infty \left\{x : |f_l(x)| >\frac1k\right\}\right) \leq \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{l=m}^\infty \mu\left(\left\{x : |f_l(x)| >\frac1k\right\}\right) = 0.$$
Therefor $\mu(E^c) = 0$.

Comment: You might want to use `\bigcup` and `\bigcap` rather than `\cup` and `\cap`. Also you can use `\left` and `\right` to ensure the parantheses and braces have the correct height.